# Duvida sobre query no delphi 7

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7

Estou com um certo problema ao tentar executar uma query de update no meu banco de dados, o delphi dá erro como sintaxe incorreta, porém não consegui achar o problema. Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor ?

Segue prints:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use parâmetros (parameters) ou trate as aspas na montagem do SQL , pesquise por quotedstr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente:

```
'UPDATE Tbl_aluno SET nome = '+QuotedStr(edit_nome.text)+'
WHERE PRONTUARIO ='+QuotedStr(.....)
```

O QuotedStr garante que o parâmetro fique entre aspas, por exemplo: nome='AUGUSTO'

Answer (score 2):

O Erro ocorreu porque sua consulta não tem aspas nos campos de texto.

Existem algumas formas de colocar aspas em uma string no delphi:

1. Função QuotedStr('string'):

   ```
   ShowMessage(QuotedStr('teste'));
   ```
2. Usar três aspas simples:

   ```
   ShowMessage('''teste''');
   ```
3. Concatenar com o código ASII39

   ```
   ShowMessage(#39+'teste'+#39);
   ```

   ou

   ```
   ShowMessage(Chr(39)+'teste'+Chr(39));
   ```